# Installing scipy 0.17.0 in PyCharm 4.5 virtual environment in Win64

Tags: python, scipy, pycharm

I downloaded a program [https://github.com/frnsys/hosny] that contains a requirements.txt list. All packages are easily installed automatically via PyCharm 4.5.5 in a specific environment.

However, scipy==0.17.0 does not install (I suppose pip install does not work with scipy).

I activated the environment and I tried to install from there manually `pip install scipy==0.17.0` I also tried to download the wheel, but I was also not able to find a wheel that is approprate for a windows 64 machine. See here the available choices https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy/0.17.0

How else can I try?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you can use Christof Gohlke wheels, http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: But I wanted the specific 0.17.1 version. I found a download, but I haven't been able to locate it again...